# Is there a way to suppress deprecation warnings about a specific final class in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, suppress-warnings

My project depends on a library that deprecated a **final** class. It's hard to migrate to a substitute class and we don't have time to do it now. At the same time, I don't like it when there are a lot of warnings in my code, so I would like to suppress warnings for which I made a decision to not fix them right now. However, I would like to still know about all other deprecated classes. Ideally, I would like to do it project-wide. I could not find a way to do it in Java.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. Maybe it's possible to achieve this in it?

Comment: Well, one option is to wrap it in a proxy class in your project and use only that. How hard that is will depend on the number of methods and fields and how it is used.

Comment: It would be pretty hard in my case because I have to pass objects of the deprecated class into library code, and because the class is final I would not be able to create a drop-in replacement and simply change imports. I would have to do a massive refactoring which I don't want to do for a cosmetic issue.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the situations where this will be tricky. You'd have to unwrap the proxy to pass the original back to the library.